# How to make project available to whole organization?

Tags: azure-devops

I have a Project with only a project Wiki.
The rest of the features I have disabled.

I would like to make this Project available as read-only to the entire organization.

I tried adding a member to the 'readers' team, but there is no 'all users' group or 'entire organization' or something like that.

Comment: You either add everyone in the organization to the DevOps team for that project, or you [make the project public](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/public/create-public-project). But there's a chance a DevOps project might not be the best solution for hosting just a wiki.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. It can't be public, I just want the project to be accessible throughout the organization. So public but still protected if you will. But it seems you're right i'd have to manually add each user. "But there's a chance a DevOps project might not be the best solution for hosting just a wiki" Could you elaborate? En de groeten uit Zwolle trouwens.

Comment: There are quite a few options for hosting a wiki. You could think about using SharePoint, Confluence, [Nuclino](https://www.nuclino.com/) or hosting your own based on for instance a static site generator like [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/). Groeten uit Eindhoven ;)

Comment: @rickvdbosch Ah I get your gist, Well right now the only reason I use this seperate project, is for a downloads page. We have some pipelines that publish build artefacts, and i have wiki page that lists the latest software from a couple pipelines. Then when you click a link you get to taken to the right file(s). Thanks for your suggestions though, I would eventually like to move away from this and use a seperate static site generator or something to distribute the files among colleagues.

Comment: @sommmen Not get your latest information. Just want to check whether below answer is helpful for you? If yes, you can accept the answer which can also benefit for others who has same puzzle with you and we could archive this thread. Also, feel free to leave comment below if still has any puzzle about it:-) Have a nice day.

Comment: Hi @HughLin-MSFT i've accepted your answer. Together with the comments from rick I know enough for now - thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this issue, you can [add a group rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/assign-access-levels-by-group-membership?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page) . Go to the Users tab of Organization settings, and then select Group rules. This view shows you all of your created group rules. Select `Add a group rule`.

[image]

[image]

Then just add users to this group rule.